# Adapter duplicating on Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi im new to programming and my issue is when i switch tabs on my navigation. My data duplicates when loading it again.

```
httpClient.get(url, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>, response: JSONArray) {
                for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                    val seminar = Seminar.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i))

                    seminarsAdapter.add(SeminarItem(seminar))
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseString: String?, throwable: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("Seminars Fragment", throwable?.localizedMessage)
            }
        })
```

Comment: So clear adapter list before `add` if you need to update data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the list before add new items, but in case that you will want to add them one by one or something more of logic in the future I suggest you add `DiffUtil` inside your `Adapter` to manage the content of your `Adapter`

> DiffUtil is a utility class that can calculate the difference between two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the first list into the second one.It can be used to calculate updates for a RecyclerView Adapter.

Give a look to [this post](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00) which explains how to implement it together with an `Adapter` and a `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

If `seminarsAdapter` already have some data, you will add to the existing set of data.

Maybe, add a `clear` method to your `seminarsAdapter`-type and call it before in `onSuccess(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpClient.get(url, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>, 
response: JSONArray) {
if(seminarsAdapter.size()>0){
seminarsAdapter.clear();
}
            for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                val seminar = Seminar.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i))

                seminarsAdapter.add(SeminarItem(seminar))
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseString: String?, throwable: Throwable?) {
            Log.d("Seminars Fragment", throwable?.localizedMessage)
        }
    })
```

clear seminarsAdapter list in on response of api call so that data won't repeat.
try above code

Comment: the .size is an unresolved reference. My seminarsAdapter is FastAdapter<>